# Why does Chrome not load the correct CSS in emulation mode?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, responsive-design, emulation

I have a CSS file that contains media queries for big and small screens, 851px min. When I shorten manually the page width, the proper CSS is loaded. However, in Chrome's emulation mode, the CSS media query isn't the right one. In Firefox, it works (icons are inline normally, and then vertical when screen under 852px.

Normal mode chrome: [image: normal]

Less wide manually chrome: [image: good query]

Google Chrome Emulation mode (under 851px wide screen) (iphone 6s): [image: glitch]

FIREFOX:

normal mode firefox:[image: normal firefox]

Less wide manually firefox: [image: good firefox]

firefox Emulation mode (under 851px wide screen): [image: great emulation]

can someone explain why the emulation works on firefow and not with chrome?

Comment: the resolution is set to 384x640. change that to test different sizes

Comment: I did, I tried everything

Comment: did you reload the page as it suggested? The viewport is very important when it comes to responsive designs

Comment: i see `media="(min-width:851px)"` try `@media (min-width: 851px) {` instead

Comment: No, I commented that out, and put it in the CSS, no success though